# jboss as 7: JBAS014639: Attribute enabled is not writable (deployment attribute)

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I've deployed an application to all of mine server-groups through jboss-cli and the application became enabled to all groups. until there that's ok!

BUT

I need to **disable** (not undeploy) the app from one of my groups (called "honda") though jboss-cli. the problem is that this option is only available through web console.

when I go through jboss-cli and execute this

```
/server-group=honda/deployment=app01.war:write-attribute(name=enabled, value=false)
```

I got the response

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"domain-failure-description" => "JBAS014639: Attribute enabled is not writable"},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I've already looked for 'JBAS014639: Attribute enabled is not writable' at google but not found any resource about the *enabled* attribute of **deployment**

please help me

Answer (score 0):

With :read-resource-description on the WAR you see:

```
        "enabled" => {
            "type" => BOOLEAN,
            "description" => "Boolean indicating whether the deployment content is currently deployed in the runtime (or should be deployed in the runtime the next time the server starts.)",
            "expressions-allowed" => false,
            "nillable" => true,
            "default" => false,
            "access-type" => "read-only",
            "storage" => "configuration"
        },
```

Since access-type=read-only you get the error. You have another field:

```
            "status" => {
            "type" => STRING,
            "description" => "The current runtime status of a deployment. Possible status modes are OK, FAILED, and STOPPED. FAILED indicates a dependency is missing or a service could not start. STOPPED indicates that the deployment was not enabled or was manually stopped.",
```

So I guess what you want is that your WAR has enabled=false and status=STOPPED and that your WAR is not removed. You get this by using one of:

```
:read-operation-names
{
"outcome" => "success",
"result" => [
    "add",
    "deploy",
    "read-attribute",
    "read-children-names",
    "read-children-resources",
    "read-children-types",
    "read-operation-description",
    "read-operation-names",
    "read-resource",
    "read-resource-description",
    "redeploy",
    "remove",
    "undefine-attribute",
    "undeploy",
    "whoami",
    "write-attribute"
]
}
```

In this case you use :undeploy to disable the application and :deploy to enable it. Thats what the web-console does.